# When using clwb "panic: Tried to write unmapped address" in Gem5 X86

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, gem5

I am running a linked list with each node having **512Bytes** allocated using malloc. I am then flushing cache line aligned addresses (using **clwb**) from this 512Bytes to measure the flush overhead. The benchmark works fine in Linux X86 system. But while running in gem5, I am getting following error. Can someone please point me to possible issue

Gem5 command :

**gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt gem5/configs/example/se.py --cmd=$command --options="$options" --l1d-hwp-type=StridePrefetcher --l2-hwp-type=BOPPrefetcher --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --mem-type=DDR4_2400_16x4 --caches --l2cache --mem-size=10GB**

$command and $options takes benchmark values

```
panic: Tried to write unmapped address 0x56318e53ed40.
PC: 0x20ee, Instr:   CLWB_M : clwb   %ctrl155, DS:[rcx]
Memory Usage: 10697132 KBytes
Program aborted at tick 225239086116
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z15print_backtracev+0x2c)[0x563187fada8c]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z12abortHandleri+0x4a)[0x563187fbfb2a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x128a0)[0x7f8ba9c998a0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7)[0x7f8ba8275f47]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141)[0x7f8ba82778b1]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(+0x51809f)[0x5631875da09f]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN6X86ISA9PageFault6invokeEP13ThreadContextRK14RefCountingPtrI10StaticInstE+0x57d)[0x56318780562d]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN13DefaultCommitI9O3CPUImplE10commitHeadERK14RefCountingPtrI13BaseO3DynInstIS0_EEj+0x8ec)[0x563187daafac]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN13DefaultCommitI9O3CPUImplE11commitInstsEv+0x529)[0x563187dabac9]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN13DefaultCommitI9O3CPUImplE6commitEv+0xaf0)[0x563187dad180]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN13DefaultCommitI9O3CPUImplE4tickEv+0xd8)[0x563187dade48]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN9FullO3CPUI9O3CPUImplE4tickEv+0x150)[0x563187dbdef0]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN10EventQueue10serviceOneEv+0xd9)[0x563187fb5c59]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z9doSimLoopP10EventQueue+0x87)[0x563187fd6097]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z8simulatem+0xcba)[0x563187fd70ea]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(+0xdb6e71)[0x563187e78e71]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(+0x6226ce)[0x5631876e46ce]
```

PS: The benchmark works fine with other flush variants, ie **clflush** and **clflushopt**

Thanks a lot, I am trying to figure out the issue from couple of days, but could not yet

benchmark https://github.com/arunkp1986/Test

Comment: You're missing source for `$command` so this isn't a [mcve].  But it sounds like you might have found a bug in GEM5, unless there's some reason the program might run differently inside GEM5 which could reveal a bug in your benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not attach attach the code thinking that will cause confusion, I am editing the question with link to benchmark git

Comment: As  mentioned by you, it may be a bug in Gem5,  I am using an earlier version,  not yet updated to latest version of Gem5, since I ran multiple other experiments on this version with out any trouble earlier,

Comment: You can't reproduce this with a more minimal [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, I will try that way and update here. Thanks once again